Assigned To Me Dashboard - Azure DevOps
Is it possible for me to create a dashboard using the "Assigned To Me" widget and configure it to all employees? I don't see any sort of configuration within this widget that would allow me to.
Also, it only works with tasks not with projects, Issue or EPIC?
I tried looking on Google, MS and Azure DevOps boards "Assigned To Me" widget configuration.

Refer to this doc: Assigned to me

Displays the list of active work items assigned to the currently logged in user. The list ignores closed, removed, cut, or deleted work items and other work item types, which aren't aligned to any backlogs.

When we use the Assigned to me widget, it will show the list of active work items assigned to the currently logged in user.
We are not able to configure it to all employees. And it will only show active task work items by default.
To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use Queries(Boards -> Queries) to filter the work items assigned to target user. Then you can use Query Result widget to configure the assigned work items to each employee.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Create query and add filters to get related work items(assigned to target user). You can add any custom filters in query.

Step2: Save the query to Shared Queries.
For example:

Step3: Use Query Result widget in dashboard to show the query result.

Result:


Thank you, Kevin! I truly appreciate the time you took to answer this question. It helped quite much.

@Caio Glad to know that it can help you. It's my pleasure
